# Copy A Collection Mongo DB using Java Without Iterator for DbAdmin login

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-java

I'm a newbie to `mongo`, using *Java Mongo Driver* to connect and perform db related operations. I've read about roles in `mongodb` and aware that the role "dbAdmin" has some restrictions on the commands he run after getting authenticated.

I've a task to update a collection from **UnCapped to capped**. To do this, from stackoverflow posts, I've read to copy the collection to temp, delete old one and rename this temp as the desired collection.

I see a problem now with dbAdmin login at the step : copying the collection. The code I've used is :

```html
MongoCursor<Document> cur = selectedCollection.find().iterator();
while (cur.hasNext()) {
    Document obj = cur.next();
    tempCollection.insertOne(obj);
}
```

on calling .iterator(), code is throwing MongoQueryException saying "not authorized on myDb to execute command { find: "testCapped", filter: {} }"

From other posts, I've used this code :

```html
DBCursor dbCursor = mongoInstance.getDB(dbName)
    .getCollection(selectedCollectionName)
    .find();
while (dbCursor.hasNext()){
    //
}
```

In this, at `dbCursor.hasNext()`, code throws the same error..!
Any alternatives for this?

- MongoDB version : **3.2.10**
- Mongo-Java-Driver : **3.2.2**

Comment: Can you add the stacktrace to the post ?

Comment: Command failed with error 13: 'not authorized on myDb to execute command { convertToCapped: \"testCapped\", size: 120 }' on server 127.0.0.1:27017. The full response is { \"ok\" : 0.0, \"errmsg\" : \"not authorized on nov14Db to execute command { convertToCapped: \\\"testCapped\\\", size: 120 }\", \"code\" : 13 }"}}}

I know its because of the role **dbAdmin** doesn't have certain privileges like find(), copyTo(), aggregate() etc, but I need a work around..

Comment: Am just wondering whether the answer is helpful to resolve the issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**MongoDB version - 3.2.6**

**Mongo Java Driver - 3.2.2**

Please check whether you have everything mentioned in the below step:-

**1) Privileges required for user which has 'dbAdmin' role assigned to it:-**

```
> db.getUser("dbAdminUser");
{
        "_id" : "test.dbAdminUser",
        "user" : "dbAdminUser",
        "db" : "test",
        "roles" : [
                {
                        "role" : "dbAdmin",
                        "db" : "test"
                },
                {
                        "role" : "readWrite",
                        "db" : "test"
                }
        ]
}
```

**2) If you don't have the user which has 'dbAdmin' role assigned to it, use the below script to create user 'dbAdminUser' and assign the appropriate role. You may need to change the database name "test" accordingly.**

```
db.createUser( { user: "dbAdminUser",
                 pwd: "password",
                 roles: [ { role: "dbAdmin", db: "test" },                          
                          "readWrite"] },
               { w: "majority" , wtimeout: 5000 } );
```

**3) Code to copy from uncapped collection to capped collection**

This is the similar code that you have with proper user connected to the database. I have used the user **"dbAdminUser"** as created in the above steps.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        MongoClient mongoClient = null;
        MongoCredential mongoCredential = MongoCredential.createScramSha1Credential("dbAdminUser", "test",
                "password".toCharArray());

        mongoClient = new MongoClient(new ServerAddress("localhost", 27017), Arrays.asList(mongoCredential));

        DB db = mongoClient.getDB("test");

        DBCursor dbCursor = db.getCollection("Account").find();

        while (dbCursor.hasNext()) {
            DBObject dbObject = dbCursor.next();
            System.out.println(dbObject);
            db.getCollection("AccountCapped").insert(dbObject);         
        }

        mongoClient.close();

    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer..!  Yep I do know about the dbAdmin role, I was trying to play around with it and didn't add "readWrite" privilege to him that caused the restrictions. Anyway thanks for the detailed explanation :)

Comment: Could you please accept the answer if it was helpful?

Comment: Done :)
If you find my question useful, please upscale it as people can find. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible problem you're facing (Second one will probably hold true if first solution didn't work if done properly) :

**You didn't authenticate**

This is simple to solve, just authenticate using `MongoClient client = new MongoClient(new MongoClientURI("mongodb//user:password@localhost/database"))`

replace `user`, `password`, `localhost` and `database` with appropriate string.

reference : [mongodb authentcation](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.0/driver/reference/connecting/authenticating/)

**You didn't create an user with appropriate role**

For this, you'll have to refer to [mongodb creating user with specific role](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/method/db.createUser/%20create%20user) instead.

Comment: Thanks for the effort but its not useful for me. I've already gone through all the steps of authenticating the user. Regarding the role, I tried for any possibility to exist if the dbAdmin doesn't have "readWrite" privilege included in java.